# How to resolve this linker error?

Tags: c++, opencv, linker, g++, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to use a compiled library inside an Eclipse project. The compilation goes fine but during linking i get an error. Below is the verbose generated on eclipse console.

g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "readInput"  ./readInput.o -llibopencv_calib3d.so -llibopencv_contrib.so -llibopencv_core.so

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_calib3d.so  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_contrib.so  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_core.so
```

I dont know even after providing the library paths why is the linker giving error that it could not find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have all required libraries: for `libSOMETHING.so`, specify `-lSOMETHING` instead of `-llibSOMETHING.so`. Omit the initial `lib` and final `.so`.

Comment: thanks Anton. It worked. Can you point out come document to fill up my knowledge gap.

Comment: Search for `-l namespec` in `man ld`, or for` -l library` in `man gcc` (the latter doesn't mention `.so`, but gets the overall idea).